# Fmap and map, I can't see the difference

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand what the functors are, but so far I can't. What's the difference between these 2:

```
Prelude> fmap (+1) [1..9]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Prelude> map (+1) [1..9]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: Try with `(Just 42)` instead of `[1..9]` and you'll be enlightened.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For lists, there is no difference, `map` is just `fmap` specialised to lists.

`fmap` has a more general type:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

this means it can be used with any functor e.g.

```
fmap (+ 3) (Just 4)          -- Just 7
fmap (+ 4) (+ 3) 1           -- 8. Functions are functors where fmap = (.)
fmap read getLine :: IO Int  -- IO is a functor
```

while map has type

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

If you look at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#fmap), the functor instance for lists defines `fmap` as `map`:

```
instance Functor [] where
    fmap = map
```

Comment: You can really drive this home by giving a specific example of something other than lists that one can use `fmap` on, like `Maybe` or `IO`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez - Thanks for the suggestion, I added some examples.